# Converting python dataframe to json format

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary

Im trying to convert a python dictionary to json .
**Input dataframe** looks like this:

```
user_id |last_update_time |states| tile                       | update_time | message
11       |1571737828      |S231  |{'Action1': [200, 250, 300],|1571737828   | traffic
                                  'Action2': [150, 200, 400]}
22       |1571737828      |S450  |{'Action1': [100, 150, 400],|1571737828   | traffic
                                  'Action2': [350, 500, 700]}
```

Already tried this, but it does not provide the required output format as shown below in the expected json output format

```
adf = input_df.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('message').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

**Expected json output** file:

```
{
  11:{ 
           "states": "s123", "last_update_time":111342342342,
           "tile": {
               "Action1": [200, 250, 300],
               "Action2": [150, 200, 400]
                      }, "update_time":111342342342
           },
  22:{ 
           "states": "s124", "last_update_time":1113423442342,
           "tile": {{
               "Action1": [100, 150, 400],
               "Action2": [350, 500, 700]
                      }}, "update_time":1141342342342
           },
"message":"traffic"
}
```

A solution for this output would really help me.

Comment: I am guessing that you are using Pandas dataframe? If so, have you tried this function ? 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
# you set the the user_id as index
adf=df.set_index('user_id')

# you convert the dataframe to a dict
# keys are dataframe indexes (user_id)
adf.to_dict(orient='index')
```

The output is the desired.

Comment: This is almost what i want , but in every line of the output it will contain a key value-pair of "message":"traffic". But I need it only once which will be after the entire data has been outputted and then "message":"traffic". In the desired output the message is only once and not for every data row outputed. Hope this helps you to understand.

Comment: Why "message":"traffic" is in every row?

Comment: This is the output I have received:    
```
{'11': {'states': 's123',
  'last_update_time': 1571737828,
  'tile': "{'Action1': [200, 250, 300], 
            'Action2': [150, 200, 400]}",
  'update_time': 1571737828,
  'message': 'traffic'},
 '22': {'states': 's124',
  'last_update_time': 1571737828,
  'tile': "{'Action1': [100, 150, 400], 
            'Action2': [350, 500, 700]}",
  'update_time': 1571737828,
  'message': 'traffic'}
}

Comment: But expecting this:
    
{'11': {'states': 's123',
'last_update_time': 1571737828,
'tile': "{'Action1': [200, 250, 300], 
  'Action2': [150, 200, 400]}",
'update_time': 1571737828},
'22': {'states': 's124',
'last_update_time': 1571737828,
'tile': "{'Action1': [100, 150, 400], 
  'Action2': [350, 500, 700]}",
'update_time': 1571737828},
'message': 'traffic'
}

Answer (score 0):

The following line should give you the result you expect, assuming that the `id_user` is your dataframe's index :

```
df.to_json("/path/to/myjson.json", orient="index")
```